# Have a question on calculating the number of strings in a set. No idea how to do it. From a sample paper:

Tags: combinatorics

I know that the paper has a solution, I just don't quite understand how to get there. Would appreciate being pointed in the right direction if possible.

[image: Sample question]

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand about the solution.  What specific parts of the solution do you not understand?  Have you never heard of the product rule before?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I think I can work out the first part quite easily using the product rule, with some explanation of "Length 10". I'm not quite getting the difference between an element and a string I suppose?  

An explanation of part two would be great.

Comment: The items you are counting in the first part are "1111111111", "1111111112", "1111111113", ..., "2334235613", ..., "6666666664", "6666666665", "6666666666".  That is, sequences (*or "strings"*) of length $10$ whose entries (*or "characters"*) are all elements from the set (*or "alphabet"*) $N_6$.  Compare this to the strings of length $3$ which are "111", "112", "113, "114, "115", "116", "121", ... etc...   These strings are themselves elements of the *set of strings* and we are wishing to count how many such strings there are.

Comment: One string is considered to be different than another if they are of different length and/or if there is a position in the first string which has a different character than the corresponding position in the second string.  For example the string "1122334455" is different than the string "1122364455" since the sixth position in the first was a 3 while the sixth position in the second was a 6.  Similarly, "123" is different than "321" despite the same characters occurring with the same frequency... the order of the characters was different.

Comment: As for part 2... you are tasked with counting those strings who have exactly seven occurrences of the character "1", no more and no less, i.e. counting the number of strings in the list "1111111222", "1111111223", ... "1121131114",...,"6651111111", "6661111111".  This also is merely an application of the rule of product, having first chosen which of the seven positions were occupied by 1's and then deciding from left to right what the remaining positions were occupied by (*knowing that they were no longer allowed to be 1's themselves*)

Comment: Thanks a lot @JMoravitz I'm getting the first part. How do I apply the product rule to the second part of the question though?

Comment: Choose which seven of the ten positions were occupied by $1$'s.  There are $\binom{10}{7}=C(10,7)=120$ such choices.  Then, for the left-most position not chosen to be occupied by a $1$ choose which non-$1$ character occupies the position in $5$ ways.  Then for the second left-most position not chosen to be occupied by a $1$ choose which non-$1$ character occupies the position in $5$ ways.  Do the same for the last position as well again in $5$ ways.  Multiplying these gives $\binom{10}{7}\cdot 5\cdot 5\cdot 5$.  For the first step, this is a standard sub-problem with a standard known solution